# How do I make Vim get the number of rows of the terminal from which it starts?

Tags: vim, terminal, line, row

My work setup has several terminals open, at different heights (e.g. number of lines). How do I make Vim obtain that number of lines so that it can set itself accordingly with `set lines`?

I'm on bash with iTerm2.

**Update:** If my `.vimrc` doesn't have a `set lines` statement, Vim should adjust itself by default.

Comment: Before this gets moved...: What terminal emulator are you running? VIM does this by default. This sounds more like your terminal emulator not properly reporting the number of lines it has.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Vim's default behaviour is to take up all of the available height. Or 24 lines if it can't get the information from the Terminal emulator according to `:h lines`.

`set lines=52` works in MacVim/GVim but it's not really supposed to do anything useful in CLI Vim besides, eventually, changing the terminal's window height.

From my limited use of iTerm2 Vim behaves as it should. So do you want Vim to take less vertical space than what is available? Or more?

Comment: Thank you, removing the `set lines=52' statement restored Vim's default behavior in iTerm2.

Answer (score 0):

Though the reason didn't require it, in case someone comes across this while trying to figure out how to get the number of rows in a terminal at startup... the answer is to use "&lines".

Eg. to enforce laststatus to display unless you are working in a small window.

if &lines > 10 | set laststatus=2 | endif